# Calculating neuron outputs and derivatives

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, neural-network, cuda

This function runs very often.  `cudaMemcpy` is at the start and works very slowly. How can I change this function to avoid this? I already have `inputs` in device memory.

```
void OpenNNL::calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives(double * inputs, double * deviceOutputs, double * deviceDerivatives)
{
    int inputsCount = _inputsCount;

    double * deviceTemp;
    double * deviceInputs;

    cudaCall(cudaMalloc ( (void**)&deviceInputs, inputsCount*sizeof(double) ));

    cudaCall(cudaMemcpy ( deviceInputs, inputs, inputsCount*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice ));

    for(int i=0;i<_layersCount;i++)
    {
        cudaCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceTemp, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i]*inputsCount*sizeof(double)));

        dim3 threadsMul = dim3(BLOCK_SIZE, 1);
        int blocksCount = floor((double) _neuronsPerLayerCount[i]*inputsCount / threadsMul.x) + 1;
        dim3 blocksMul = dim3(blocksCount, 1);

        weighting<<<blocksMul, threadsMul>>>(deviceTemp, deviceInputs, _neuronsInputsWeights, _inputsInPreviousLayers[i], inputsCount, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i]);

        cudaCall(cudaFree(deviceInputs));

        cudaCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceInputs, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i]*sizeof(double)));

        dim3 threadsSum = dim3(BLOCK_SIZE, 1);
        blocksCount = floor((double) _neuronsPerLayerCount[i] / threadsSum.x) + 1;
        dim3 blocksSum = dim3(blocksCount, 1);

        calculateOutputsAndDerivatives<<<blocksSum, threadsSum>>>(deviceOutputs, deviceDerivatives, deviceInputs, deviceTemp, _neuronsBiases, inputsCount, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i]);

        inputsCount = _neuronsPerLayerCount[i];

        cudaCall(cudaFree(deviceTemp));
    }

    cudaCall(cudaFree(deviceInputs));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to minimaze memory allocations.

Allocate memory for `deviceTemp` and `deviceInputs` only once (in the constructor, for example):

```
cudaCall(cudaMalloc ( (void**)&deviceInputs, some_big_value * sizeof(double) ));
cudaCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceTemp, some_big_value * sizeof(double)));
```

And in `calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives`, reallocate memory only if needed:

```
if (cur_deviceInputs_size < inputsCount)
{
    cudaCall(cudaFree(deviceInputs));
    cudaCall(cudaMalloc ( (void**)&deviceInputs, inputsCount*sizeof(double) ));
    cur_deviceInputs_size = inputsCount;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is some redundancy within the `for` loop which could be removed:

```
   dim3 dimGrid = dim3(blocksCount, 1, 1);
   dim3 dimBlock = dim3(BLOCK_SIZE, 1, 1);

   for (int i = 0; i < _layersCount; i++)
   {
       cudaCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceTemp, ... ));

       size_t blocksCount = ...

       weighting<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(...);

       // no need to call cudaFree on deviceInputs every iteration 
       // b/c cudaMalloc will be writing to the same location in device memory
       cudaCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceInputs, ... ));

       blocksCount = ...

       calcOutputsAndDer<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(...); 

       // rest same as before
   }
```